# JTable refreshing

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jpanel

I use JTable with horizontal and vertical scrollbars. My JTable has empty space after rows with data. 
When I open panel that is situated down of my table it hides a part of JTable and scrolling appears on JTable. This is normal behavior, but then I close that panel, empty space without data becomes grey instead of white color. 
This only happens when I have horizontal scrollbar on my JTable. I suppose I must force JTable to repaint, I tried `resizeAndRepaint()` on `TableHeader` and `JTable` but it didn't work.

Please help! Thanks!
Here is resize() code invoked if any resize action was performed on table

```
for (int i = 0; i < columsNum; i++){
        TableColumn column = this.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
        int preferedSize = //current size
        int minimumSize = // min size
        if (minimumSize != ColumnSizeCalculator.UNDEFINED_WIDTH)
            column.setMinWidth(minimumSize);            
        column.setPreferredWidth(preferedSize);        
    }   

    this.revalidate();
    this.repaint();
```

Comment: In case Martin is not familiar with the SSCCE concept, see: http://sscce.org

Comment: Martin,  that is not an SSCCE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, a JTable does not fill the viewport of a scrollpane in the vertical direction. Try to call

```
table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
```

on your table, then repainting the table should work.